# Determine best cdn for image and remember it

Tags: php

I want a way to take any input (url) and get back a number between 1-4, distributed as even as possible 25% for any input. It's important that it gets the same value of 1-4 every time.

The reason I want this is so that I can create seemingly random and evenly disturbed content for a set of CNAMEs (subdomains) for a CDN. It would take pictures that were originally `www.website.com/picture.png` and output them as

`cdn1.website.com/picture.png` or 
`cdn2.website.com/picture.png` or 
`cdn3.website.com/picture.png` or 
`cdn4.website.com/picture.png`

Effectively allowing me to bypass the browser restrictions set to a subdomain, giving me more parallel connections (Read more: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/). The reason why I want the URL to **always** pass back to a specific CDN  is for caching purposes; If the `www.website.com/picture.png` is first displayed as `cdn1.website.com/picture.png` and a second time around as `cdn2.website.com/picture.png` then the browser would not know that it has the same picture cached already under cdn1 and would download the same picture twice, rather than relying on cache.

---

Here the suggested php at it, but I as you can see from results that I don't get that 25% ratio I would like for small sample set. I am looking for alternatives that would also be somewhat close to 25% distribution for small samples.

```
<?php

$num_array = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    $num_array[]=(crc32(genRandomURL()) % 4)+1;
}


print "<pre>";
print_r(array_count_values($num_array));
print "</pre>";

$num_array = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $num_array[]=(crc32(genRandomURL()) % 4)+1;
}


print "<pre>";
print_r(array_count_values($num_array));
print "</pre>";


function genRandomURL($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $string = "";
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }

    return "http://www.website.com/dir/dir2/dir3/".$string.".png";
}


?>
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 2489
    [1] => 2503
    [2] => 2552
    [4] => 2456
)
Array
(
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 1
)
```

Comment: You could just use `hash%4`?

Comment: Why not just use a standard hash function, and then extract 2 of the resulting bits?

Comment: Yeah, I made it more complicated than it had to be. I edited the question to be more specific with a downfall of this method

Comment: You will never get a consistent distribution with such small sample sets, and limited entropy. Your CRC32 hash is probably the best way using that method. Other methods would be using a counter, or saving an array of images and using a predefined lookup.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a hash of the name, getting the last two bits of that hash, then finally converting them back into a decimal number. Should return the same value so long as your name doesn't change.

```
function img_id($string){
    $hash = md5($string); // create hash
    $bin_hash = base_convert($hash, 16, 2); // convert to binary
    $last_bits = substr($bin_hash, -2); // get last two bits
    $img_int = bindec($last_bits)+1; // turn bits to integer, and + 1
    return $img_int; // will be number from 1 to 4
}

$picture = 'picture.png';
$cdn_id = img_id($picture);
$url = "cdn{$cdn_id}.website.com/{$picture}";
```

If your name might change then you could also look at doing a hash of the actual file contents.